# Is the current political system inadequate for the size of our population?

Tags: political-system

Although I don't know much about politics, I do know that the history of democracy as a system of governance stretches right back to Ancient Greeks. Which makes me question whether a new system is required to govern the unforeseen size of our current population?

I know this isn't strictly scientific, but to me it appears that its effectiveness acts inversely proportional to the size of the electorate. This is evident by the decreasing number of people turning out to vote, as the population grows.

http://www.ukpolitical.info/Turnout45.htm

Just wanted to throw that out there.

Comment: "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time."  (Churchill).  Do you have another suggestion? Do you think there's something wrong with the current system other than turnout?   This question *is* on topic and not too broad, since it is a concrete, political question, but it's very opinion-based without an example of an alternative form of government to consider or a specific goal to measure "adequate" by.

Comment: @Bobson I think the alternative would be devolution of most powers to smaller sized cities or states where fewer people are voting, since this question only examines the size of the population. Although it almost seems from the question that the goal of government is to get people to vote.

Comment: @lazarusL - That would be one alternative, yes.  Others could be to have a ruling council decided by something other than votes, who themselves are the ones to vote on things (oligarchy).   Or disenfranchising groups - if we go back to only allowing white male landholders to vote, the electorate will be much smaller.  There's plenty of ways to cut down on the electorate without going so far as to have a single dictator/autocrat in charge of everything.

Comment: What's "our"? Democracy seems to work for more than 1G Indians.

Comment: The chart you linked doesn't indicate that the number of voters is consistently shrinking. Take the points yourself and use linear least squares to make a linear function, which will disprove your baseless claims.

Answer (score 3):

While the question of "Adequate" or "not adequate" isn't really answerable properly (due to the lack of a precise definition of "adequacy"), the spirit of the question can be answered to the tune of "is there a clear decline of the pro/con ratio of a democratic system with the growth of governed population".

The answer to that is "Yes", via several concurrent mechanisms:

1. **Insulation - in a sense of removal of the consequences - of a lot of votes from the voters**.

   In a small principality, many consequences of a decision made by the government are immediately affective of the voters.

   - You vote to stop funding an expensive program for military-industrial complex? Yay. Your local weaponsmith just went bust and died of hunger.
   - Oh, and the neighbouring tribe heard of that, ramped up their weapons producton, and conquered you next year.
   - You vote to stop funding F22, F35, and a bunch of other weapons programs? That has no direct negative effect on you since the chances are, neither you nor anyone else you know is employed in the military-industrial complex, never mind the parts of it that participate in those programs. And USA is so big and mighty, you are unlikely to see your town conquered next year for lack of F22 (and what happens 30 years from now isn't on most voters' minds).
2. **Ease of lobbying by narrow interests**

   In a large population, any corrupt decision by government (using the non-criminal meaning of corruption) has very low relative negative (obvious) impact on random populace member; and very high immediate positive impact on a special interest benefiting from that corrupt decision.

   Since this is directly caused by increase in the numerator with near-constant denominator, the greater the size of the polity, the more benefits and opportunities for corruption.
3. Harder to escape.

   If you live in a small polity, and don't like its policies - you can move to the nearest polity. Most likely, it's in a similar-ish environment (one city state in Greece is different from another - but they are both city-states in Greece. Or even more so in USA - one state is very much like the other, making the tangible and intangible cost of moving low.

   When the polity gets large, a major nation-state, an average citizen can't escape so easily, both logistically; as well as culturally. For all the wailing and gnashing, neither Michael Moore, nor Sarandon, moved to Canada when Bush was elected. Nor did their right-wing equivalent moved when Obama was. And these are rich, powerful celebrities who do have the wherewithal to move more than almost any other member of society.
4. Somewhat related to #3, the large polity can also purposefully make it hard to escape.

   If you move from a small city state to another, your former city state can't come after you and <strike>rob</strike>tax you on all your assets at the time of move. They can't make up a silly law to pursue you and force another polity to arrest you. USA (or Russia, or France) can do both, as it wishes.
5. As a consequence of #3 and #4, a large polity can pass laws heavily impacting individual society members with greater impunity.

   If you raise taxes on a super wealthy person in New York, they can move to Connecticut with virtually no problem (it did happen after NY passed major tax increase on hedge funds).

   If USA chooses to do the same tax increase in federal taxes, not nearly as many impacted people would be willing, or even able, to move elsewhere.
6. Small polity means everyone lives together and there are personal consequences to being bad.

   You voted to take away my cow and we live in the same village? Next time you depend on me as a fellow community member - e.g. look after your kids, or defend you from an aggressive fellow, etc... - I won't do that. Or worse, I'll get aggressive towards you without going over the line of what's illegal.

   You voted to take away a cow from a guy 20 states over? What are they gonna do, not send you a Christmas card? Post an insulting message on Facebook?

   You as a village elder awarded public funds to a miller who offered you free dinners at the expense of everyone else? The miller will be shunned. So will you, once you seek an honest job after your power term is over.

   You award $10B in public funds to a company or a union who contributed to your election as US President? Sure, some people will shun you after your power term ends. But plenty of others won't know, or care, so you have plenty of opportunities to make $100K a week on a lecture circuit.
7. Small polity means everyone knows everyone.

   People in Arkansas probably knew that Clinton was a philanderer, and an accused rapist. Nobody of Arkansas knew - and thus he got elected.

   This gets execerbated in the era of a few powerful mass media outlets who control the information, and somewhat improved in the current Internet world - but not by much. Small village gossip reaches EVERYONE. Left-wing blogs can raise a storm about some offense of a right wing candidate, but the latter's supporters, or more importantly, undecided independents, probably don't read left-wing blogs anyway, so they still wouldn't know (for the opposite direction, see John Edwards adultery scandal).
8. Large polities tend to be split into voting areas.

   If said areas have first-past-the-post voting, a minority opinion population of any given area is basically robbed of being a full participant in a democratic process - the votes of any Republican in NY, or a Democrat in Utah, don't matter at all in terms of Presidential election.
9. The consequences of bad decisions by electorate/elected are higher.

   If some village decides to do something spectacularly stupid (attack a stronger village, or plant feed corn instead of food), the very worst that can happen is a couple hundred people in that village suffer or die.

   When a large polity does that, millions of people die in WWI/WWII, or suffer from hunger like when Russia (admittedly, not a democracy but the point is irrelevant to form of government) chose to plant corn under Khruschyov.
10. As a consequence of #9, the moral hazard of Too Big To Fail rears its ugly head.

    When a village votes to give everyone free luxury car, and soon goes bancrupt, nobody else is much affected. It means the village is less likely to do something so bad, and even if they do, the population of nearby villages with saner policies benefit.

    When Greece (not a large country) does the same, they have to bailed out by <strike>everyone else</strike>Germany, lest they sink the whole financial system.

    When someone the size of USA does it... nobody is even thinking about what happens if bankruptcy happens.